# Splitting the wordpress loop in gutenberg blocks created with acf

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I have a question around displaying posts and custom posts in Gutenberg blocks using Advanced Custom Fields. I want to query all posts of a post type, but split the loop as I need different layouts for individual posts. I want to display the posts in a grid that has different rows and column heights (see image below) and not use external css for this, as I'm working with TailwindCSS. For this I would normally use a function that splits the loop, as described here: https://vanrossum.dev/20-splitting-the-wordpress-loop

```
//functions.php
function posts_from_loop( $amount, $callback ) {
    global $wp_query;

    $count = 0;

    while ( ( $count < $amount ) && ( $wp_query->current_post + 1 < $wp_query->post_count ) ) {
        $wp_query->the_post();

        $callback();

        $count++;
    }
}
```

and use it like the following:

```
//home.php
<div class="grid">
    <?php
        posts_from_loop( 2, function() {
            get_template_part( 'partials/post-w50' );
        });
    ?>
</div>

<div class="grid">
    <?php
        posts_from_loop( 3, function() {
            get_template_part( 'partials/post-w33' );
        });
    ?>
</div>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) { 
    the_post(); 
    ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'partials/post-w100' ); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

However, the function does not work inside a Gutenberg block **and also not with custom post types.**  I tried to set it up like the following

```
//block.php
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'posts',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',

);

$loop = new WP_Query($args);
?>
<?php if ($loop->have_posts()) : ?>
    <div class="container mb-2">
        <?php
        posts_from_loop(1, function () {  ?>
            <?php get_template_part('template-parts/partials/post', "featured"); ?>
        <?php }); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="container grid grid-cols-1 gap-2 mx-auto md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-4">

        <?php
        posts_from_loop(4, function () {
            get_template_part('template-parts/partials/post', 'color');
        });
        ?>

        <?php while (have_posts()) {
            the_post();
        ?>
            <?php get_template_part('template-parts/partials/post', "image"); ?>
        <?php } ?>

    </div>

<?php endif ?>
```

Would be nice, if someone could help me with

1. Splitting the wordpress loop inside gutenberg blocks efficiently without a counter
2. Splitting the wordpress loop with custom post types and acf

[Post-Grid that I want to display with splitting the loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riaPU.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `posts_from_loop` is acting on the `global` query, you have a custom one. The quickest fix would be to pass the custom query in as an optional parameter, falling back to the global if not provided (for BC with any code that is already using the function).

```php
function posts_from_loop( $amount, $callback, $query = null ) {
    if(!$query) {
        global $wp_query;
        $query = $wp_query;
    }

    $count = 0;

    while ( ( $count < $amount ) && ( $query->current_post + 1 < $query->post_count ) ) {
        $query->the_post();

        $callback();

        $count++;
    }
}

posts_from_loop(
    4,
    function () {
        get_template_part('template-parts/partials/post', 'color');
    },
    $loop

)
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you very much!
It seems like I can't access the global post inside a gutenberg block. So even when looping through normal posts, I have to do a custom query with args and post_type => "post". Is there a way to do the same as I would within for example "home.php"?

Comment: When you say "inside a gutenberg block" I'm a little confused. A block lives inside a post which gets rendered as part of a loop. Once you are inside the block there's nothing to split anymore. Inside of a post/page you could split the blocks up, however.

Comment: Sorry, I meant inside the block.php file. It seems like this .php is "acting different" than a template file for example, where I could simply use the posts_from_loop function without specifing the post-type.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still confused. In the posted example you are using `$loop = new WP_Query($args);` which means that's a custom loop, not the native loop. You could reassign it to the global but that can mess things up. Or am I not understanding?